# Typeahead list of words not appearing in correct location

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, typeahead

I've been playing with the Twitter bootstrap template, testing some concepts for an upcoming site, and everything has been working fine.

Now the designer has handed over the actual website and I'm having trouble implementing some of the features from my development site based on the Twitter bootstrap template. My main one at the moment is the typeahead feature:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

The Typeahead is working on my new site but the list of words isn't appearing below the input field - it's way off to the right and I'm not sure why that is the case. You can see this for yourself at this simplified version of an input form at:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/34923164/test.html

If you start typing "walking" into the first intput field you'll see the list appear off to the top right - how do I get it back under the input field itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly importing the Bootstrap stylesheet. The typeahead uses the *dropdown* class (as you can see from the class that is created on the *ul*) which tells it where to display correctly (among other things).

If you don't want to use their styling, it'll be a little more confusing, but you can basically jack the info you need out of the class. The most important will likely be the *position* type and *top* and *left* properties.